# How can I call a test set at the end of each epoch during the training? I am using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using Tensorflow-Keras to develop a CNN model in which I have split the data set into train, validation, and test sets.  I need to call the test set at the end of each epoch as well as train and validation sets to evaluate the model performance. Below is my code to track train and validation sets.

```
result_dic = {"epochs": []}
json_logging_callback = LambdaCallback(
                on_epoch_begin=lambda epoch, logs: [learning_rate],
                on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs:
                result_dic["epochs"].append({
                    'epoch': epoch + 1, 
                    'acc': str(logs['acc']), 
                    'val_acc': str(logs['val_acc'])
                }))
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                      validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      epochs=epochs,
                      callbacks=[json_logging_callback])
```

output:

```
Epoch 1/5
1/1 [==============================] - 4s 4s/step - acc: 0.8611 - val_acc: 0.8333
```

However, I'm not sure how to add the test set to my callback to produce the following output.

Expected output:

```
Epoch 1/5
1/1 [==============================] - 4s 4s/step - acc: 0.8611 - val_acc: 0.8333  - test_acc: xxx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display your test accuracy after each epoch, you could customize your `fit` function to display this metric. Check out this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit) or you could, as shown [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2548), define a simple callback for your test dataset and pass it into your `fit` function:

```py
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                      validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      epochs=epochs,
                      callbacks=[json_logging_callback, 
                                 your_test_callback((X_test, Y_test))])
```

If you want complete flexibility, you could try using a [training loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/basic_training_loops).

Update: Since you want to have a single JSON for all metrics, you should do the following:

Define your `TestCallBack` and add your test accuracy (and `loss` if you want) to your `logs` dictionary:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class TestCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, test_data):
        self.test_data = test_data

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        x, y = self.test_data
        loss, acc = self.model.evaluate(x, y, verbose=0)
        logs['test_accuracy'] = acc
```

Then add the test accuracy to your results dictionary:

```
result_dic = {"epochs": []}

json_logging_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(
                on_epoch_begin=lambda epoch, logs: [learning_rate],
                on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs:
                result_dic["epochs"].append({
                    'epoch': epoch + 1, 
                    'acc': str(logs['accuracy']), 
                    'val_acc': str(logs['val_accuracy']),
                    'test_acc': str(logs['test_accuracy'])
                }))
```

And then just use both callbacks in your `fit` function but note the order of the callbacks:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                      validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      epochs=epochs,
                      callbacks=callbacks=[TestCallback((x_test, y_test)), json_logging_callback])
```

Comment: I wonder how to merge two callbacks (json_logging_callback, and your_test_callback)? I am going to add recorded results from your_test_callback into the json_logging_callback?  @AloneTogether

Comment: Just like I showed you in the example, you would have two separate callbacks. There is no need to merge them

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I need to write several metrics plus loss value for train, validation, and test in a json file. The "json_logging_callback" does the job for train and validation; though, I'm not sure how to somehow append "your_test_callback"  to "json_logging_callback" to keep track of all train, val, and test sets.

Comment: Ok, I see. Check my updated answer.